# Fact to Fact Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssas, data-warehouse

I have two fact tables:
1. FactPOLine: it has all the PO lines.
2. FactInvoiceLines: it has all the invoice lines.

There is a one-to-many relationship between invoice and po.  i.e. each invoice line can have only one po line, but a po line can have multiple invoice lines.

How do I model this relationship? I think connecting two facts is not recommended.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Fact tables are joined for analysis by the dimensions that they have in common.  For example, FactPOLine and FactInvoiceLines might both have keys to the following dimensions:

- Item / Product
- Customer
- Supplier
- Carrier
- Date

Date is a special case in which their might be multiple dates associated with each line.  However, it makes analysis much easier if you can cut by one primary date for each table so that you can analyze both by year, quarter, month.

Lastly, it may be useful to add a junk dimension to hold the po number and line and link both tables to it.  In that case, a user could analyze by PO.  This is helpful for more operational type reports.

**EDIT:**
In your comments you note that business wants to analyze by PO.  This probably makes sense if the company only has a handful of POs per year.  However, it is more likely the case that they have thousands, ten of thousands or more and this makes it very unwieldy to for detailed analysis.

I suggest asking the 5 whys and trying to discover their goals.  i.e. Why do you want to analyze by PO?  Why do you want to see all the data?  Why do you want to see those unfilled POs? ...

Eventually, you'll arrive at some hard measures that you can add to your reports and data models.  Things like a flag for open PO lines, or a semi-additive measure for % complete.  Whatever it is that their after, you can probably get them exactly what they need rather than 1000 page report by PO line.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have these dimensions and both facts are connected to them.  But business would like to analyze the invoices against POs and therefore we need a direct link between POs and Invoices.  Two ways to achieve that.  Add an FK in invoice line to PO line, OR, add this junk dimension.  Which way should I go, or do you think there is another way?

Comment: Do not in any way add an FK from fact to fact. The cleanest approach is by linking them through a dimension. This is also what your bi tools will be expecting, so it will make the user experience less clunky. I'll update my answer with another tip based on your comments

Comment: A PO number is not suitable for a junk dimension- it is a degenerate dimension on the PO line fact. Also, although its true that you normally link up via dimensions in common, it is definitely true that invoice number as a degenerate dimension in one fact and PO number as a degenerate dimension in another fact are related- there's no reason to prevent joining on this.

Comment: To clarify- a junk dimension is a specific technique for dealing with low cardinality flags and textual categories. Since the PO number will be very high cardinality I don't see any benefit in throwing the PO number into a dimension, when you already have it in the fact. I wouldn't bother with a FK though- just put the IDs in the fact tables so people can join on them when needed.

Comment: @Rich - Sure, my mistake in miss-classifying the dimension, call it degenerate or mini.  Eventually, this will wind up in SSAS or some such tool, the benefit of putting it into a single dimension is so that you can cut by one field.  Having the PO and line in both tables will only allow you to analyze by one or the other.  Multidimensional will force you to put the text field into another table, regardless.  I suggest handling this problem up front.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that would be referred to as a degenerate dimension.  The perfect example is purchase order or invoice numbers.  All of the po attributes are associated with other dimension, except the PO #.  These numbers feel like a dimension attribute, but they don't exist until the fact event occurs.  They belong in the fact table, but will be used to create a new dimension containing a single attribute.  All of the other attributes will still exist in the other analytical dimensions.

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/01/fact-tables-and-dimension-tables/

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/06/design-tip-46-another-look-at-degenerate-dimensions/

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/

Answer (score 1):

These IDs can both be modelled as 'degenerate dimensions' in the fact table itself as per the answer from Wes.

You can just plonk the POLine # alongside the InvoiceLine # in the InvoiceLine table for those situations where you have to join on those IDs.

You might even get away with having a fact table surrogate key in POLIne which you can use in InvoiceLine as a foreign key. It isn't perfect, but its practical.

Mark is correct that you normally link via dimensions rather than via such IDs, but the kind of linkages you describe are acceptable in dimensional modelling when needed.